# &nbsp causes XHTML5 validation failure

Tags: html, validation, utf-8, xhtml, w3c-validation

I'm in the process of applying an "HTML4.5" approach to an existing XHTML 1.0 Strict site in Internet Explorer. The idea is to change the Doctype and apply semantic classes matching the new elements of HTML (<`div class="aside">`, etc.) and do all that I can get away with, without Internet Explorer breaking (e.g. applying new `<input>` type attributes).

The only problem I've encountered is that W3C's validator doesn't like `&nbsp;` or `&copy;`, while [html5.validator.nu](http://html5.validator.nu) has no problem.

I know that HTML5 validators are experimental at this stage. Should I replace `&nbsp;` with something? If so, what?

My charset on this particular site is `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is fine in the `text/html` HTML5 and it validates for me at W3.

Where it *won't* validate is in XHTML5. The only built-in entities in XML are `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;` and `&apos;`. XHTML1 brought in the HTML entity list by means of the DTD referenced by `<!DOCTYPE>`, but (X)HTML5 no longer uses a DTD, so that means in the XML serialisation you can't use the HTML entities.

A character reference such as `&#xA0;` is still okay. And if you're serving your page in the right encoding you can just include a U+00A0 No-Break Space character directly without escaping:  . (Of course that's going to be annoying to edit if your text editor doesn't visually distinguish the no-break and standard space.)

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace all the `&nbsp;` with `&#160;`

Comment: i guess the correct decimal entity for `&nbsp;` should be `&#160;` or one could also use hexadecimal entity `&#xa0;`

Comment: Some Other Useful HTML Character Entities - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp